# Odd Even Subarrays

Tags: c++, performance, array, c++14, dynamic-programming

I've been trying to understand Dynamic Programming lately, here's the question I just attempted:

> You are given an array A of N positive integer values. A subarray of this array is called an Odd-Even subarray if the number of odd integers in this subarray is equal to the number of even integers in this subarray.
>
> Find the number of Odd-Even subarrays for the given array.

Solving this on hackerearth, [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/odd-even-subarrays-72ad69db/description/)!

I immediately connected this with Matrix-Chain Multiplication from CLRS, which tries all sub-arrays. To optimise it for this question, I used the `numEvens` array to track number of even ints from index 0 to i. This takes \$O(n)\$ time. This way I don't have to actually *scan* every sub-array to see if it's Odd-Even or not. `evensIJ` tells me how many even ints are in `arr[i..j]`. I still have to *visit* every sub-array though, thus the \$O(n^2)\$ nested loops, where `l` is the length of the sub-array.

Here's the code, it takes as input the array `arr` of ints and it's size `n`:

```
long int numArrs(int arr[], int n)
{
    int numEvens[n], l, i, j, evensIJ;

    if (arr[0] & 1) numEvens[0] = 0;
    else numEvens[0] = 1;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        numEvens[i] = (arr[i] & 1) ? (numEvens[i - 1]) : (1 + numEvens[i - 1]);

    long int count = 0;
    for (l = 2; l <= n; l += 2)
    {
        if (l > n) break;
        for (i = 0; i < n - l + 1; i++)
        {
            j = i + l - 1;
            evensIJ = numEvens[j] - numEvens[i] + ((arr[i] & 1) ? 0 : 1);
            if (2*evensIJ == (j - i + 1))
                count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

I believe my code is correct but it give a `Time Limit Exceeded` error on larger test cases, even though it solves all smaller ones correctly. Any way to optimise it? Should I completely abandon this approach or should I optimise on this approach somehow?

Any style advise is also appreciated since I've been coding in Python3 for the last two years and have just shifted to C++14 last week because I need speed for competitive coding and all.

Also, side note, changing

```
evensIJ = numEvens[j] - numEvens[i] + ((arr[i] & 1) ? 0 : 1);
```

to

```
evensIJ = numEvens[j] - numEvens[i - 1];
```

makes the code incorrect. Am I being dumb for not getting why this happens?

Comment: *"... it give a Time Limit Exceeded ..."* – so this is from some programming challenge? Can you add the link to the problem description?

Comment: @MartinR added link to the challenge.

Comment: check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-subarrays-with-same-even-and-odd-elements/) for a O(n) solution

Comment: @juvian yes! thank you very much, this certainly is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the code review:

> ```
> long int numArrs(int arr[], int n)
> ```

With C++14, you can do better than use built-in arrays (decaying to a pointer in a function, whatever the signature says): use rather `std::vector`, or `std::array` if you know the size at compile time.

> ```
> {
>     int numEvens[n], l, i, j, evensIJ;
> ```

Don't declare your variables unless you're ready to define them. Wait as much as possible to keep the declaration near to where you use your variable.

> ```
>     if (arr[0] & 1) numEvens[0] = 0;
>     else numEvens[0] = 1;
> ```

Try not to clutter your code with useless repetitions. For instance you might write:

```
numEvens[0] = (arr[0] & 1) ? 0 : 1;
```

or

```
numEvens[0] = !(arr[0] & 1);
```

By the way, don't hesitate to declare short functions that the compiler will inline, they'll make your code clearer:

```
constexpr bool is_odd(int i) { return i & 1; }
```

> ```
>     for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
>         numEvens[i] = (arr[i] & 1) ? (numEvens[i - 1]) : (1 + numEvens[i - 1]);
> ```

Raw loops (`for` loops which don't say what they're doing) should be replaced with standard, named algorithms whenever you can. Look for instance at `std::partial_sum`.

> ```
>     long int count = 0;
>     for (l = 2; l <= n; l += 2)
> ```

try to give your variables more meaningful names, e.g : `l` -> `length`

> ```
>     {
>         if (l > n) break;
>         for (i = 0; i < n - l + 1; i++)
>         {
>             j = i + l - 1;
>             evensIJ = numEvens[j] - numEvens[i] + ((arr[i] & 1) ? 0 : 1);
>             if (2*evensIJ == (j - i + 1))
>                 count++;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return count;
> }
> ```

This nested loop is why it's taking too much time. There's an `O(n)` algorithm for this, which relies on dynamic programming (your program doesn't, in my opinion).

The idea is to use a map to keep track of the imbalances you've seen; whenever you come back to an imbalance, it means that you're correcting it, and so you increase your result by the number of times you've visited it:

```
long int count_balanced_subarrays(const std::vector<int>& input) {

    std::map<int, int> imbalances;
    imbalances[0] = 1; // 0 is the initial position, that's why it's already marked

    unsigned odd_count = 0;
    unsigned even_count = 0;

    long int res = 0; 
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        if (input[i] & 1) ++odd_count;
        else ++even_count;
        res += imbalances[odd_count - even_count]++;
    } 
    return res;
}
```

Comment: holy damn! There's even a _std::partial_sum_!? C++14 is amazing lol. Thanks for the great review, I'll be sure to correct these issues moving forward. I believed storing the partial sums was a form of Dynamic Programming but the O(n) solution is certainly the best, thanks!

Comment: *Remark:* A *single* count variable  (which is incremented or decremented) would be sufficient.

Comment: @MartinR: Indeed, but I wanted to make the algorithm more obvious (it isn't that intuitive)